# finding out if user used for DirectoryEntry connection is an administrator

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, directoryentry

I have an existing DirectoryEntry connection and I want to check if the user that was used for the creation of this DirectoryEntry belongs to a specific group.
anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Shuky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any magic, easy way to do this....

On the `DirectoryEntry` object, you do have a `UserName` property which should hold the name of the user that was used to create this entry, if a specific user was supplied. Using that user name, you could do a directory lookup and find that user and check whether that user belongs to the `Administrators` group (or any other group) - but it's not exactly a one-liner.